# pypyodbc cursor.execute() List index out of range

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

It's late, I'm tired - I hope I am just making a stupid mistake but I can't seem to see it. Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong? If I run the SQL on SQL Server Management studio, it works fine. I can run other SQL statements against the cursor, just not this one.

Thanks in advance

System:

```
Windows 7, Python 3.4, SQLServer 2008, pypyodbc
```

Query:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name='{MyDBName}')
BEGIN
 ALTER DATABASE {MyDBName} SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
 DROP DATABASE {MyDBName}; 
END
```

CODE:

```
cursor.execute(query)
cursor.commit()
```

EXCEPTION:

```
ex = {IndexError} list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you please show the traceback from that exception?  As shown it's rather "out of context"...

Comment: I finally fount the problem, I'll post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For posterity sake, I finally found my way through it and will share in case anyone reads this later:

It turns out that I need the autocommit property set to true when making the connection:

```
auto_commit = true
with pypyodbc.connect(cnx, auto_commit) as connection:
     cursor = connection.cursor()              

     cursor.execute(query)
     cursor.commit()
```

Note also that I change my query to just:

```
DROP DATABASE {MyDBName};
```

However, that alone didn't fix it without the auto-commit.

I hope that is helpful to someone, time for bed : )

Comment: Not sure if this is a difference with the latest version or a typo in the answer, but for anyone else dealing with this, I had to use `autocommit=True` (note the lack of underscore). `auto_commit=True` threw up concatenation errors, and the parameter without `=True` also didn't work.

Comment: @Aujury Thanks, my answer wasn't clear. I had a variable named 'auto_commit'. I should have included that in the code. I've edited it now - thanks for correcting me.